# comboBox not updating text as it should

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to update a combobox two times, once when another combobox is selected to populate itself with some description and twice to update itself when a description from the dropdown menu is selected, the first one works with no problem but when i try to update it a second time the text doesn't update, the console output shows true value tho.

piece of the code where combobox1 is modified

```
private Dictionary<string, string> prezziDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

private void comboBox9_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedArticolo = comboBox9.Text;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedArticolo))
    {
        PopulateComboBox1(selectedArticolo);
    }
}

private void PopulateComboBox1(string selectedArticolo)
{
    try
    {
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(Form1.credentials))
        {
            con.Open();
            string query = "SELECT descrizione, prezzo FROM prezzi_articoli WHERE articolo = @articolo";
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@articolo", selectedArticolo);

                using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Clear();

                    prezziDictionary.Clear();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string descrizione = reader["descrizione"].ToString();
                        comboBox1.Items.Add(descrizione);

                        string prezzo = reader["prezzo"].ToString();
                        prezziDictionary[descrizione] = prezzo;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedDescrizione = comboBox1.Text;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedDescrizione))
    {
        if (prezziDictionary.TryGetValue(selectedDescrizione, out string prezzo))
        {
            comboBox1.Text = prezzo;
            Console.WriteLine("b " + prezzo);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Prezzo not found for selected description.");
        }
    }
}
```

i tried different approaches, even removing combobox from parent and recreating it, adding it to the combobox and changing it's index etc. but it still shows only the description (it is set to DropDown), am i missing something?

Comment: Try changing this comboBox1.Items.Add(descrizione); --> comboBox1.DataSource = descrizione;

Comment: The `SelectedIndexChanged` event is raised before the Text property of a ComboBox is updated (hence, whatever you set here is overwritten later). If you REALLY want to do that (changing the Text to a value that is not in the list. Not a good thing), you can use `BeginInvoke()` to set the Property (e.g., `BeginInvoke(() => comboBox1.Text = prezzo);` <= .NET 6+ syntax), or handle the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event instead -- You should probably set the DataSource of your ComboBox to `prezziDictionary.ToList()`, and also set the `DisplayMember` to "Key" and `ValueMember` to "Value"

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you want to display the description of each item in the ComboBox, and if it is not available, you want to display that alert message.

If this is your intention, try modifying this part of the code:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string selectedDescrizione = comboBox1.Text;

      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedDescrizione))
      {
          if (prezziDictionary.TryGetValue(selectedDescrizione, out string prezzo))
          {
              comboBox1.Text = prezzo;
              Console.WriteLine("b " + prezzo);
          }
          else
          {
              MessageBox.Show("Prezzo not found for selected description.");
          }
       }
}
```

To:

```
bool IsGet = false;
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedDescrizione = comboBox1.Text;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedDescrizione))
    {
        if (prezziDictionary.TryGetValue(selectedDescrizione, out string prezzo))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(prezzo))
            {

                IsGet = !IsGet;
                comboBox1.Items.Clear();
                comboBox1.Items.Add(prezzo);
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
                Console.WriteLine("b " + prezzo);
            }
            else if (!IsGet)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Prezzo not found for selected description.");
            }
            else
                IsGet = !IsGet;
        }
            
    }
}
```